# Trying to insert another span tag before another

Tags: javascript, html

Well, i'm trying to insert a span tag before another one to act like an ID of it depending on the other spans value. There are severall of these spans with an specific classname. So im looping thru every single one of them to edit one at the time. But the result I'm getting is just that one span is getting inserted to the top span, or no span is inserted.

I've tried using to just att the "id" to inneHTML like "A-"+class.innerHTML. But that gave same result.

```
<h4>ÄN:<span class="nummer">1023</span></h4>
```

```js
function arendebokstav() {

  var nummerid = document.getElementsByClassName("nummer");
  var bokstavid = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < nummerid.length; i++) {
    if (nummerid[i].textcontent <= 999) {
      bokstavid = '<span class="newcssclass">A-</span>';
      nummerid[i].insertBefore(bokstavid, nummerid[i])
    } else if (nummerid[i].textcontent <= 1999) {
      bokstavid = '<span class="newcssclass">B-</span>';
      nummerid[i].insertBefore(bokstavid, nummerid[i])
    } else if (nummerid[i].textcontent <= 2999) {
      bokstavid = '<span class="newcssclass">C-</span>';
      nummerid[i].insertBefore(bokstavid, nummerid[i])
    } else if (nummerid[i].textcontent <= 3999) {
      bokstavid = '<span class="newcssclass">D-</span>';
      nummerid[i].insertBefore(bokstavid, nummerid[i])
    } else if (nummerid[i].textcontent <= 4999) {
      abokstavid = '<span class="newcssclass">E-</span>';
      nummerid[i].insertBefore(bokstavid, nummerid[i])
    }
  }
}
```

No error message getting shown. I want it to write out "A-999" and "B-1000" and so on but all I get is "999" "1000" etc etc

Comment: Have you tried `textContent` instead of `textcontent`?

Comment: [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) should be called on the parent node, not on the node you are inserting before.

Comment: That is a lot of duplicate code

Comment: Ye, will refactor the code when it first get it working hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your code as follows:

```js
function arendebokstav() {
  let mySpan = document.getElementById('mySpan');
  let nummerid = document.getElementsByClassName("nummer");
  
  for (let i = 0; i < nummerid.length; i++) {
    let letter;
    if (nummerid[i].textContent <= 999) {
        letter = 'A-'
    } else if (nummerid[i].textContent <= 1999) {
        letter = 'D-'
    } else if (nummerid[i].textContent <= 2999) {
        letter = 'C-'
    } else if (nummerid[i].textContent <= 3999) {
        letter = 'D-'
    } else if (nummerid[i].textContent <= 4999) {
        letter = 'E-';
    }
    
    let newItem = document.createElement("span");
    newItem.classList.add("newcssclass");
    newItem.textContent = letter;
    
    mySpan.insertBefore(newItem, mySpan.childNodes[0])
  }
}

arendebokstav();
```

```css
.newcssclass {
     color: red;
 }
```

```html
<div id='mySpan'>
    <span class='nummer'>3000</span>
</div>
```

Here's what you've missed:

- `insertBefore` needs to append a `node` to the parent.

For a more detailed explaination consult the [doc](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<span id="mySpan">1000</span>

<p>Click the button to insert a word before text.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction('mySpan', 'A-')">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction(id, word) {
  var newItem = document.createElement("span");
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(word);
  newItem.appendChild(textnode);

  var list = document.getElementById(id);
  list.insertBefore(newItem, list.childNodes[0]);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```